# Unable to create Custom (Virtual) fields in 'rallytreegrid' but can in 'rallygrid'

Tags: rally

If I use a 'rallygrid' I can create custom columns like the below:

```
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
columnCfgs: [
    'FormattedID',
    'Name',
    {
    text: 'Custom Value',
    renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
        return myArray[record.data.FormattedID].myValue;
        }
    }],
context: this.getContext(),
enableBulkEdit: true,
showRowActionsColumn: true,
storeConfig: {
    model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
    pageSize: 25
}
```

When I do this, my 'Custom Value' does what I want. Hooray !!

But, if I replace this with a 'rallytreegrid' like below, it errors:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
    models: ['portfolioItem/feature'],
    autoLoad: true,
    enableHierarchy: true
}).then({
    success: this._onStoreBuilt,
    scope: this
});

_onStoreBuilt: function(store) {
    this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
                    store: store,
                    context: this.getContext(),
                    enableEditing: true,
                    shouldShowRowActionsColumn: true,
                    enableBulkEdit: true,
                    enableRanking: false,
                    columnCfgs: [
                        'FormattedID',
                        'Name',
                         { text: 'Custom Value' }
                    ]
                });
}
```

Because of that 'Custom Value' field I get the error, even with or without the renderer part.

```
Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: Unable to get property 'substring' of undefined or null reference
```

If I remove that 'Custom Value' field it works grand.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had a good answer for you- this seems like a bug.  Fortunately it is simple to work around- you just need to add the xtype for the column.  The regular grid must be correctly defaulting this whereas the treegrid is not.

```
{ 
    xtype: 'gridcolumn', 
    text: 'Custom Value', 
    renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
        return 'rendered output goes here';
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thought I was going crazy, but thanks for that. A simple workaround. I should have thought of that.